# Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm following a tutorial to create a Meteor app and I've been having the same error regarding different things in the developer console.

```
> Meteor.users.find().count();
VM2034:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined(…)(anonymous function) @ VM2034:1

> Session.set('pageTitle', 'A different title');
VM2035:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Session is not defined(…)
```

From researching the problem, the 2 solutions that come up are: (1) doing

```
meteor add session
```

which I have done; (2) updating the Meteor version but I am running Meteor 1.3.3. Neither works.

EDIT: After doing `meteor update`, the Meteor error disappeared once but came back the second time I tried a command based on Meteor.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you included the javascript in your page? If so, have you included them before the code which references them?

Comment: I'm new to Meteor but it should do all of that automatically, right? I never included anything explicitly so far and everything else is working.

Comment: Strangely, after running `meteor update`, the Meteor error no longer appears. The Session one persists.

Comment: In what shell are you running this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to set the session outside the client folder you will get this error. Which is why you must do:

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
 Session.set('pageTitle', 'A different title');
}
```

Then you can check it worked simple write in console:

```
Session.get('pageTitle')
```

Will output: `"A different title"`

Good luck!

Comment: That works! And the Meteor one is working as well (for no apparent reason...). Thanks!